# "What surprised about the movie is..." vs. "what surprised me in the movie is..."

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if there us any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> What surprised me **about** the movie is how the main character faced up to the immense hardship.
>
> What surprised me **in** the movie is how the main character faced up to the immense hardship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is **in** a movie, it is part of the movie - something you can perceive when you watch it, for example:

- My favourite actor is **in** this movie.
- He is a character **in** this movie.
- I liked the special effects **in** this movie.
- The music was great **in** this movie.

You could not replace the preposition "in" with "about" in any of those above sentences.

Things you could say "about" a movie could incorporate all of the above (but would need to be phrased differently, for example, "The music was something I liked **about** this movie") yet you could also incorporate details that are not necessarily perceived from watching it, for example:

- What I liked **about** this movie was the cinematography.
- An interesting fact **about** this movie is that it is based on a true story.

In the case of your two examples, they mean the same - the detail you share is both something *in* the movie, and also an observation *about* it.